# Is it correct to have a URL which using both backslash and forward slash in it? (Node.js express multer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, multer

I'm using the *multer* package to let visitors upload their images. Everything works fine, but in the end, the path to the image is something like this:

`"/images\the-picture.jpg "`

Even in the database (I'm using MongoDB), the path is saved like this:

`imageurl: images\the-picture.jpg`

I'm using this middleware to give the *multer* the proper filter:

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Math.round(Math.random() * 100000) + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single("image"));
```

And in the controller I simply get the path to file:

`const imageurl = image.path`

Do I need to fix this URL problem or I can ignore this?